# Не работает ajax пагинация на мобильных устройствах

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Написал код на загрузку контента на сайт при помощи ajax. На компьютерах все работает отлично, но вот на мобильных устройствах пагинация не работает. Не исчезают старые данные и не меняются на новые. Думаю проблема именно в javascript.
Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {// Event after click on pagination element
    $(".slider-pagination ul li").on( "click", "a", function (e) {

        // Check where we are
        link = document.location.href.split('/')
        provider = link[link.length - 2]

        if (provider != 'life' && provider != 'mtc' && provider != 'combi') provider = 'kyivstar'
        var click = $(this);

        // Find parent block type
        block = click.closest('section').attr('id')
        if (!block) block='combi'

        // Get information about data in pagination
        page = e.target.id
        page_number = page.split('+')[0]
        result = page.substr(page.indexOf("+") + 1);


        //Start ajax load
        $.ajax({
            url: "/libs/ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { page : page_number, info: result, provider:provider, block:block },
            success: function(data) {
                numbers = JSON.parse(data);

                // Now we remove all tags and data from block and create new empty list
                if (provider != 'combi') {
                    click.parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.number-list ul').remove();
                    click.parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.number-list').append('<ul></ul>')
                } else {
                    click.parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.number-list ul').remove();
                    click.parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.number-list').append('<ul class="inner"></ul>')
                }

                // Insert new data into block
                for (var num in numbers){
                    if (provider!='combi') {
                        click.parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.number-list ul').append(
                            '<li><a><span>' + numbers[num].code + '</span> ' + numbers[num].number + '</a></li>'
                        );
                        // you can show both index and value to know how the array is indexed in javascript (but it should be the same way it was in the php script)
                    } else {
                        number = numbers[num].number
                        numbers_array = number.split(',')

                        click.parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.inner').append(
                            '<li><ul class="inner-list" id="'+num+'"></ul></li>'
                        )

                        for ( var i in numbers_array) {
                            click.parent().parent().parent().parent().find('#' + num).append(
                                '<li><a>' + numbers_array[i] + '</a></li>'
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }

                // No we must mark current element of navigation
                pages_qty = click.parent().parent().parent().find('li').size();
                // Delete class active from all pagination elemenets
                for (i = 1; i <= pages_qty; i++) {
                    previous_id = i + '+' + result
                    previous_page = document.getElementById(previous_id)
                    previous_page.className = ''
                }
                // Mark current element of pagination
                e.target.className = 'active'
            },
            error: function(){ console.log('error')}
        });
});});
```

При клике на пагинацию удаляю у родителя весь контент, включая теги с данными, а после добавляю теги заново, уже с новым контентом. После удаляю класс у всех элементов пагинации и применяю класс к текущему элементу пагинации.
Подскажите, что нужно заменить или поправить, чтобы пагинация работала и на мобильниках. 
Проверил на другом телефоне, андроиде, все работает отлично, проблема именно в iPhone Safari.

Comment: Не работает - это как? Тут не две строчки, нужно уточнить, на каком действии спотыкается.

Comment: @Mik , не исчезают старые данные и не меняются на новые. Пагинация выделяется нормально.

Comment: @ValentineMurnik, есть доступ к консоли браузера когда пробуете на мобильном устройстве?

Comment: @Grundy к сожалению, нет

Comment: Заметил небрежности в коде, которые, кстати, при некоторых обстоятельствах могут стать причиной проблем. Во-первых, Вы не все переменные объявляете с `var`, хотя по контексту они выглядят как локальные. Во-вторых, не все блоки кода заканчиваете `;` , что может вызвать ошибки, если будете сжимать скрипт. Хотел бы сказать больше именно по Вашей роблеме, но не имею возможности потестить код. Предполагаю лишь, что событие касания не распознается как `click`. Пробовали подключать спец. библиотеки, jQuery Mobile, например?